# I am unable to increment id

Tags: php, sql, web-services

I searched many stackoverflow questions it didn't help. I want to increment `id` by fetching last id from MySQL table.

I don't want to do auto-increment in MySQL table because already one column is auto incremented.

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

$created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//$json_data    = array();
$message = array();
$error = array();

if ($_GET['vendor_id'] == "") {
    $message[] = array("message" => "Values Empty");
} else {

    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT loo_id  FROM loo_list ORDER BY loo_id DESC LIMIT 1");
    if ($result) {
        $order_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) or die(mysqli_error());
        //echo $order_array['loo_id'];
    }
    $loo_id = $order_array['loo_id'] + 1;

    $sql = "insert into loo_list(loo_id,name,address,geolocation,price,facility_category,facilities,count,accessbility,image,type,category,created_vendor,days,timings,terms_conditions,vendor_approval,created,warning,url,user_ids,overall,admin_approval,updated)values('" . $loo_id . "','" . $_GET['loo_name'] . "','" . $_GET['address'] . "','" . $_GET['loo_location'] . "','" . $_GET['price'] . "','" . $_GET['facility_category'] . "','" . $_GET['facilities'] . "','" . $_GET['count'] . "','" . $_GET['accessbility'] . "','" . $_GET['image'] . "','Offerers','" . $_GET['category'] . "','" . $_GET['vendor_id'] . "','" . $_GET['days'] . "','" . $_GET['timings'] . "','" . $_GET['terms_conditions'] . "','1','" . $created . "','0','','" . $_GET['user_ids'] . "','" . $_GET['overall'] . "','1','" . $created . "')";
    $res1 = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    $message[] = array("message" => "success");
}
$json_data = array("result" => $message);
echo json_encode($json_data);

?>
```

Comment: Do any one know the answer. please help me

Comment: have to have a clue as to what you are asking to be able to answer

Comment: Can you share the output of `var_dump($order_array['loo_id'])`?

Comment: See this part $result = mysqli_query("SELECT loo_id  FROM loo_list ORDER BY loo_id DESC LIMIT 1");
if($result){
  $order_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) or die (mysqli_error());
  //echo $order_array['loo_id'];

}
$loo_id = $order_array['loo_id'] +1 ;

Comment: Its null, every time table will be updated as 1

Comment: So the problem is your `SELECT`. What is the output of `var_dump($order_array)`?

Comment: That is also null. But when i print that SELECT query in mysql it will execute

Comment: Is there any permission to fetch the data from mysql table

Comment: Probably not. You can test that by running this `SELECT` directly in SQL and see if it returns any results there. I assume it will not... I'd need to see the `loo_list` table to help you further.

Comment: I am fetching the data, it returns the last id successfully

Comment: Why do you need another incremental id if you already got an auto inc?

Comment: `select coalesce(max(loo_id, 0)) + 1  FROM loo_list` returns the next number (the `coalesce` is for the case that the tabe is empty), no need to increment it in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
if(trim($order_array['loo_id']) === ''){ 
 $loo_id = 1; 
}else{
 $loo_id = intval($order_array['loo_id']) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Its null, not entering if loop only

Comment: Its returning 0

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: No luck, now also 0

Comment: `$loo_id = 1;` set `$loo_id` as 1 in if condition rest of the code as it is instead of `$loo_id = 0;`

Comment: This also no luck

Comment: What are you trying?